# ServiceLocator pattern with autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

How can we implement a ServiceLocator class with Resolve() method inside it using Autofac. We need to implement it in Asp.net core project and a console application.

We are facing two challenges:

- We cannot simply return a class instance as it needs to be created using lifetime scope and lifetime scope should be disposed after instance usage. So we will have to return Lifetimescope or any abstraction over it, which is not intuitive.
- In context of asp.net core, we will have to create a different lifetimescope, we want to utilize lifetime scope created by .net core itself.

Thanks

Comment: We don't? That's an *anti*pattern. Autofac and other DI containers exist so you *don't* have to instantiate a dependency *inside* the class, you *invert* the depependency and let the container inject it in the constructor.

Comment: Did these links help? https://www.google.com.au/search?q=autofac+service+locator

Comment: I'd suggest having a read of http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/best-practices/#use-relationship-types-not-service-locators .

Comment: ["Service Locator is an anti-pattern"](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) - Mark Seemann

Comment: I understand that ServiceLocator is an antipattern, but there are places where it make sense. For instance in a facade class, A facade class can interact to multiple subsystems and it does not make sense to initialize all the subsystems using DI. These subsystem may not be required for current request.

Comment: .NET Core has its own DI functionality that can be configured to use Autofac as the DI container. Check [.NET Core](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/netcore.html) in the Autofac documentation and the [Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection) package. Note that all dependencies come through injection, not service locator classes

Comment: @Pragmatic it doesn't, especially when using ASP.NET Core. You'd be going against the framework. As for your case, that means your class is doing too much and needs breaking up.

Comment: `These subsystem may not be required for current request.` Could `Lazy` help for that?

Comment: I could find anyway to implement service locator, but found http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#delayed-instantiation-lazy-b which can be an alternate. It would help me in implementing Facade class where I dont want to create all the subsystem at once.

Comment: I voted on closing this question because the question lacks details about why Service Locator is required. Please add concrete examples and explanation on where in your application you need this and why. Only this way we can help you.